# Can I skip ranges when defining Named Ranges in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-forms

Like the title suggests, is there a way to skip a range or certain values when defining named values? My sheet's name is "All," and the range I have right now is All!A:B. I want to exclude A1 and B1.

I have tried `{All!A1:A1000, All!B1:B1000}`, but the named values section doesn't accept the column row format?

For further context, I am linking the spreadsheet to a Google form. I have multiple sections with the same questions, so I just want the questions one time (which are the values in row 1) and then all of the responses. I am defining the ranges like this for my query function, which is:
`={query({time_category,first_curric},"Select * Where Col3= 'class1'");  query({time_category,second_curric},"Select * Where Col19= 'class1'"); query({time_category,third_curric},"Select * Where Col19= 'class1'")}`

Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to exclude A1 and B1

go for `All!A2:B`

---

or offset it:

```
={QUERY({time_category, first_curric},  
  "where Col3  = 'class1'");  
  QUERY(QUERY({time_category, second_curric}, 
  "where Col19 = 'class1'", 0), "offset 1", 0); 
  QUERY(QUERY({time_category, third_curric},  
  "where Col19 = 'class1'", 0), "offset 1", 0}
```

Comment: Do you know why I would keep getting this error: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows. I filled in every question in the form, so I'm not sure how any values would be missing

Comment: @achromaticaries ARRAY_LITERAL error means that one side of the range is bigger than the other inside constructed array {} see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131436/186471 in your case I guess its a row count... one of your named ranges has more rows than the others

Comment: if the time_category range is all the same, and the first, second, and third curric are the same length, does it affect it if time_category and the curric ranges are different? I didn't think so just because they should take the same column space per row, but I am not sure

Comment: @achromaticaries can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Q_zxP-IolOXYkLzubls2ZK7LQAi2I29ywoCimf_Vt4/edit?usp=sharing

for some reason on the first sheet with query, I get the array_literal error, but on the others, it says the Col35 doesn't exist even though I used the same formula

Comment: @achromaticaries see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q5uj5K8KSS8OdVDj1SPv7KO1n1ayAZx8eYDz9EbfTH4/edit#gid=61886344

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225296/discussion-between-achromatic-aries-and-player0).